# regarding the use of extern keyword

Tags: c, extern, multiple-definition-error

```
extern int var;
```

I understand that when we use `extern` keyword with a variable as shown below, memory for that variable is not allocated. (It is just a declaration)

```
extern int i = 0;
```

And I know that if we declare an `extern` variable and also provide an initializer along with that declaration, then the memory is allocated for that variable.

Also the below program is printing `0`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i; // Can I treat this as declaration/definition?
int main()
{
    printf("%d ", i);
    return 0;
}
```

I feel, here the variable `i` is being assigned the value `0`.

If (`int i;` as shown above) is definition, why below code is not giving multiple definition ERROR?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int i;
int i;
int i;
int main()
{
    printf("%d ", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without an explicit initialization, all the `int i`s in global space are called *tentative definition*. However, this is not allowed in local scope.

To quote the `C11` standard, chapter §6.9.2, *External object definitions*

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a tentative definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no external definition for that identifier, then
>   the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation unit, with an initializer equal to 0.